# Get the bytes[] from a TotalCaptureResult

Tags: android, android-camera

I am getting the TotalCaptureResults object from the camera, using the Camera2 API in Android. I am using a preview, not a single image. Is there a way to get bytes[] from TotalCaptureResults?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

All `CaptureResults` objects contain only metadata about a frame capture, no actual pixel information. The associated pixel data are sent to wherever you designated as the target `Surface` in your `CaptureRequest.Builder`. So you need to check with whatever `Surface` you set up, such as an `ImageReader` which will give you access to an `Image` output from the camera, which will give you access to the bytes[].