# Timestamp appears over black screen instead of the image captured

Tags: android, bitmap, timestamp, android-camera, capture

I have an app that has its own built in camera with camera2.
after you take a photo, it will show you your image with a timestamp over it, that's what it should do. how do I get the time stamp to appear over the image taken, rather than a black screen with a time stamp on it.

here's my code.

```
                @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


                Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
                Paint tPaint = new Paint();
                tPaint.setTextSize(35);
                tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                float pHeight = tPaint.measureText("yY");
                cs.drawText(dateTime, 20f, pHeight+15f, tPaint);


                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(_pictureUri.getPath ());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                    dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);


                    Intent intent = new Intent (CameraActivity.this, CameraReviewPhotoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _pictureUri);
                    startActivityForResult (intent, CameraActivity.Approved_Image);


            }
```

need anything else let me know.

but thank you! :)

**UPDATE:**

I wasnt grabbing the image so the canvas was working on nothing. I needed to add

`Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (String.valueOf(file));`

at the top and then

`Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedBitmap, 0, 0, decodedBitmap.getWidth(), decodedBitmap.getHeight());
dest = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);`

Comment: You do not appear to be doing anything with the captured image. Your `Canvas` is created blank, and you are drawing text on it, and that's it.

Comment: You probably miss the [ImageReader part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31092662/192373).

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! @CommonsWare you helped get me on the right path. thank you.