# How to pass android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult object to JobIntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, android-camera, android-camera2

I am working on android camera application. I have written one Service which perform operation on the `TotalCaptureResult` object. How can I pass this object to the JobIntentService ?

Comment: `TotalCaptureResult` is not `Parcelable`. If the work will be fairly short (a couple of seconds), I would avoid the `JobIntentService` and do something else for a background thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare Totally agree with you, not passing to the  TotalCaptureResult to the background thread. But we are doing CPU intensive processing on the `CaptureResult` object. Not only that we are processing multiple captures at the same time if users kill the app we lose the data. I also tried writing `CaptureResult` object using 'Gson' even that is not helpful since `Gson` is failing to convert it to `Json` string. Do you know any workaround for now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069216/get-the-bytes-from-a-totalcaptureresult check out this answer

Comment: You will need to *very carefully* pass the `TotalCaptureResult` to the service via something `static`. I say "very carefully" because you need to ensure that you don't leak memory, ensure that you can properly handle N results in a queue, etc.

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I know what you getting at. I know `CaptureResult` just has metadata and information about the Camera sensors. If it had just Image Data 'byte[]' i would have written it to 'File' and pass URI in 'Json' String.

Comment: @CommonsWare can I create a `Queue` in 'JobIntentService' where I can push the `TotalCaptureResult` object  and in `onHandle` method `poll` the `Queue` to get the   `TotalCaptureResult` object. Do you thing this method would work?

Comment: You will want to monitor the queue to ensure that work gets pulled off of it and does not pile up, as you run the risk of running out of memory due to a memory leak. I don't know how big a `TotalCaptureResult` can get, so I don't know how many items are safe to have in the queue. If you can ensure that you keep track of your memory, this approach should be OK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I really appreciate your response. One last question, what (scenario) will cause the memory leak in if I use the `Queue` in JobIntentService?

Comment: Well, just using a global `Queue` this way is an intentional short-term memory leak. The key for success is "short-term". So, if you fail to pull objects out of the `Queue`, or you fail to pull them out fast enough, that will cause longer-term problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You. I got it now.